# Ringer not ringing when phone call comes through

Tags: ringtone, volume

I have a Nexus 6 running the latest version available to it (5.1.1). All of a sudden, a few days ago, the ringer has stopped ringing when I receive a phone call. I have the volume turned all the way up, and when I listen to the sample ringtone in the settings screen, it's audible.

I'm sure I must have accidentally changed something, but have no idea what. Any ideas?

Comment: Shutdown -> Pull the battery -> Resinsert -> Turn on the phone and check..And also do you have any Call blocking apps installed? Please remove if any and try..

Comment: Go to Settings > Apps > Dialer > Check "Show notifications". That fixed my problem.